# Embed interactive matplotlib plot in a webpage

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a simple matplotlib scatter plot which uses [this code](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Interactive_Plotting)
to display an annotation when points are clicked on. I need to embed this in a webpage. How should I do this?

I found similar questions here as well but couldn't quite understand the answers. If someone could explain it a bit clearly in detail please?

Edit: I need to do something like [this](https://mpld3.github.io/examples/scatter_tooltip.html), with the interactive scatter plot being displayed in the webpage. However, on looking at the source code of the webpage, it did not look like the python code is being called.
How do I do something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to use the same code that you used before in a webpage, but using a library like [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/) and the `hover` tool would make it fairly easy to get a similar behaviour

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#hovertool