# How do I show legend for different colors in bokeh scatter plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, legend, bokeh

This is my [plot](https://cdn.rawgit.com/eldor4do/smit-results/master/cgpa.html).
I need to show the legend for the different colors used.
How do I do that?

My code for the plot:

```
def mscatter(p, x, y, c,typestr,source):
    p.scatter(x, y, marker=typestr,
            line_color="#6666ee", fill_color=c, fill_alpha=0.5, size=y*1.5,source = source)

p = figure(title="CGPA of 4th year students",tools=[hover])
mscatter(p, xdata, ydata, colors,"circle",source)
show(p)
```

Comment: @RachelGallen can those embedded inside webpages like the one here?

Comment: @RachelGallen I had asked this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807853/embed-interactive-matplotlib-plot-in-a-webpage),of embedding matplotlibs into webpages, which led me to bokeh. It's going back to square one now.

Comment: i found some documentation!

Comment: also have a look at this http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/iris.html

Comment: http://www.kousibei.net/:/bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/charts.html

Comment: please see new answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is sample bokeh documentation on [adding legends](http://www.kousibei.net/:/bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/charts.html)

You will have to modify as you see fit

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from bokeh.charts import Scatter, output_file, show

# (dict, OrderedDict, lists, arrays and DataFrames of (x, y) tuples are valid inputs)
xyvalues = OrderedDict()
xyvalues['python'] = [(1, 2), (3, 3), (4, 7), (5, 5), (8, 26)]
xyvalues['pypy'] = [(1, 12), (2, 23), (4, 47), (5, 15), (8, 46)]
xyvalues['jython'] = [(1, 22), (2, 43), (4, 10), (6, 25), (8, 26)]

scatter = Scatter(xyvalues, title="Scatter", legend="top_left", ylabel='Languages')

output_file('scatter.html')
show(scatter)
```

the above code will result in the following picture:

[image: scatterplot]

Comment: Yes but this doesn't quite seem to work for scatter plots. Over here, there are only 3 lines to be plotted, so 3 plot for line statements and 3 for legend.  My requirement is similar to plotting legend for the iris plot. The iris plot has 3 different colors, so I would a need a legend for 3 colors and their description.